# Как сделать чтобы через apscheduler выполнялось действие через 3 сек, единожды?

Tags: python, apscheduler

Как сделать чтобы через apscheduler выполнялось действие через 3 сек, единожды?
Нужно чтобы таймер запускался, через 3 сек срабатывала определенная функция, и после этого срабатывания не шел отсчет опять с выполнением функции.
Если использовать триггер 'interval', то функция будет исполняться каждые 3 сек(а мне этого не надо).

Answer (score 0):

Никак!
Нужно воспользоваться встроенным модулем asyncio, и использовать в коде следующую конструкцию:

```py
#...код...
asyncio.sleep(3)
#...код который выполнится через 3 секунды
```

Comment: Да ладно, "никак". При вызове функции просто удаляйте ее из планировщика через `scheduler.remove_job(имя_функции)`. Но на короткие интервалы в принципе не понятно зачем планировщик использовать.